# Extra space in Meta Stack Exchange menu bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, menu-bar

There is some extra space in between **Unanswered** and **Ask Question** in the Meta Stack Exchange's menu bar compared with the other menus.

[image: Extra space menu bar]

After inspect the menu bar, I can see `margin-right : 30px` applied for the element.

[image: Extra space margin right 30px]

Removing the `margin-right : 30px`, the spaces between each menu is consistence.

[image: No margin right 30px]

The extra space in menu bar is occurred only in Meta Stack Exchange, the remaining sites doesn't have that space.

Screen shot of other site's menu bar for reference:

[image: Other Stack Exchange sites menu bar]

Comment: This is by-design. Also, your circles are not freehand.

Comment: @ǝpoɔɟoʇɹɐ: Only for Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: Aye. It's always been like that, and if it were a bug someone would have noticed by now, I imagine.

Comment: Why does it matter though? Every site has its own design and different designs have slightly differing menu bars.

Comment: @animuson: Just seeing some inconsistency in menu bar compared with other sites, so reported. If it's purposely added then fine.

Comment: Then we should agree on what inconsistency should mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a pretty common thing for the "Ask Question" link to be visually separate or different from the other ones. Yes, not everwhere, but for example on [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) it has a different color, on [RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) it's right-aligned with the other links being left-aligned, on [Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) (as your screenshot shows) it's bolded, and on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) – well, just look at it (pro tip: hover your mouse cursor over it!).